# Shopware 6 dynamically change VAT

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible to change rate of VAT on checkout page?
For example I want to add condition if user is guest and commercial then use 20% rate else 0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is currently not possible, but there is a feature currently being implemented which allows for custom tax calculations.

Search for "Interface for tax services" in the [public roadmap](https://www.shopware.com/en/roadmap/).

That feature is designed to allow to connect to external tax providers for more complex tax calculation e.g. the US, but it should also allow to change the taxes by rule etc.

However keep in mind that in that case the prices in the store prior to the checkout page may not be accurate, this can have some legal implications depending on the country where the shop is operating.

Comment: the rules will be applied only if a customer logged in? Because in my case all customers are guests and I'm worried about can I use the rules for taxing.

Comment: Rules are always evaluated, but most of them require customer information (e.g. the shipping address) so those rules can only be evaluated after a customer registered, but it does not depend on whether the customer creates an account or is a guest customer.

Comment: one more thing for clarification. I just need add simple rule:

```
If 
  customer === "commercial" 
  then taxRate = 19%
else (or if customer === "private" doesn't matter) 
 then taxRate = 0%
```

will be possible implement using this new feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [module*](https://store.shopware.com/acris82076579589/b2b-mwst-steuerfrei-bei-eingabe-der-uid-nummer-inkl.-ust-id-pruefung.html) which allows to determine automatically based on the VAT ID entered if the B2B customer should pay tax, and doesn't bill tax to customers with a valid VAT ID.

*I am not affiliated with that module, but also did not test it.